# MapDB collection size issue

Tags: java, memory-management, dictionary, mapdb

I'm using MapDB 0.9-snapshot. I have some collection containing several millions of records String->String.
My problem is that the method size() on such ConcurrentMap(s) takes a lot of time and a lot of memory (I have even an OutOfMemory error).

Any other experienced such a problem?
Thanks
Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapDB needs to traverse all entries in collections to count it. You may store count in external Atomic.Long and retrieve it separately, an example is here:

https://github.com/jankotek/MapDB/blob/master/src/test/java/examples/Map_Size_Counter.java

OOEM should not happen, it is probably due to GC overhead assertion.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jan. It works. However, is quite strange to have it as external trick.

Comment: deadlink in the answer